# Ruby Rmagick: Crop/"Trim" excessive (white) space of image automatically

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, imgkit

I'm taking a "Screenshot" of HTML documents with IMGkit (https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit).
The background is *always* white (#ffffff).

IMGkit is taking 1200 x 1000 pixel big "Screenshots", and I might end up with a lot of white space as the actual content of the HTML documents may be very small.

Are there built in functions in Rmagick to crop/trim this excessive white space automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is RMagick's trim method.

Example

```
require "rubygems"
require "RMagick"
require "imgkit"

include Magick

kit  = IMGKit.new('http://localhost/test.html')
blob = kit.to_img(:png)

img = Magick::Image.from_blob(blob).first
img.trim!

File.open("test.png", "w") { |f| f << img.to_blob }
```